# I'm getting a Compilation error in my C++ error: expected an identifier

Tags: c++

Hi I'm getting the following compilation error:

error: expected an identifier
CARD_INACCESSIBLE               = -2,

I'm just trying to compile with the following enum in a header file

```
enum eSyncroErrorCodes
    {
        TEST_ANGLES_NOT_IN_RANGE        = -14,
        NOT_IN_SELF_TEST_MODE           = -13,
        DEPRESSION_INPUT_OUT_OF_RANGE   = -12,
        BEARING_TURN_OUT_OF_RANGE       = -11,
        BEARING_DIFF_OUT_OF_RANGE       = -10,
        BEARING_INPUT_OUT_OF_RANGE      = -9,
        DEPRESSION_OUT_OF_RANGE         = -8,
        TURN_OUT_OF_RANGE               = -7,
        CHANNEL_FAULT                   = -6,
        IN_SELF_TEST_MODE               = -5,
        POWER_FAILURE                   = -4,
        FAULT_ON_CARD                   = -3,
        CARD_INACCESSIBLE               = -2,
        DRIVER_API_ERROR                = -1,
        NO_REPORTED_ERROR               = 0
    } eSyncroErrorCodes;
```

if I change CARD_INACCESSIBLE to INACCESSIBLE_CARD or THE_CARD_INACCESSIBLE all is fine I can't find anything that says CARD_INACCESSIBLE is reserved in C++ so I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Is there another place in your project, perhaps in a header that you include, that defines `CARD_INACCESSIBLE` as something else?

Comment: It is defined as a macro in another header but that is not included in my header

Comment: Is that other header perhaps included indirectly? If you use GCC, you can use the `-H` flag to have the preprocessor print which headers get included from where - but whatever the case, you'll probably have to come up with a different name either for this enumerator or for that macro.

Comment: I do use GCC and I was not aware of -H and it is indeed indirectly included thanks for the pointer, I had already changed my enum but just wanted to know what the problem was. Thanks